Vacuum Protection of Gas Pressure Regulators
I have experienced issues with gas pressure regulators failing open or loosing their set points when either the inlets or the outlets are exposed to hard vacuum. Gas pressure regulators that regulate pressure from 200 bar down to 4 bar are not supposed to be exposed to a 5 kPa(a) hard vacuum, but this is a regular occurrence during Cleaning-in-Place procedures. Besides the obvious "don't expose to vacuum / use a valve" solutions, is there any other industry standard way of protecting a pressure regulator from the effects of a line vacuum?

I have not had this experience, but it could very well be an issue in certain regulator designs. My initial suggestion though is to look for other potential issues that may have caused the regulator damage. Often times we blame the most obvious process change without actually diving into the full scenario to find the root cause.
It might be good to post the exact model you are having issues with. Some more details about the CIP procedure would be helpful; I have never heard of CIP on a gas system. Operating gasses and CIP gases? Temperatures? Temperature differences? Are there any system shocks like being slammed with pressure after being at vacuum? Seal material? Have you taken apart one of the failed regulators to inspect it? If you do not have the resources to do the regulator teardown; often times a manufacturer will do this free of charge. They like the feedback on their design and its constraints and want you to keep buying from them.
Aside from all the design tricks that make the device more linear and dampen oscillations, a regulator is pretty straight forward and they are usually pretty hard to break. Even in rough use, usually the only things to fail are the seals and diaphragm. The springs typically have mechanical extension limits to protect them, but could potentially be damaged if that was not part of the design.
Pressure regulator diagram from Wikipedia:

Failing open would most likely be a seal failure. Visual inspection of the failed seal will tell you the most here. The only way I could see 5kPa vacuum damaging a seal is if the process gasses were dissolved in the material and out gas at that pressure; but that's a long-shot. I would keep an open mind and look for other possible failure modes.
Set point change could be a damaged spring, or possibly a result of the seal leaking and not being able to hold the target set point. Very unlikely vacuum would mechanically damage springs in regulator rated for such a high pressure range.
Hard Vacuum can mean different things to different industries, but usually "hard vacuum" would mean "high vacuum" and require the use of specialized vacuum pumps to achieve.
5kPa is a very "rough" or "low" vacuum. Solids have negligible out-gassing at this pressure. Even water will not boil at this pressure unless heated to 32C(90F). I doubt the presence of this vacuum level on the materials is an issue.
